# How to use postgis to reproject 900913 to a different bounding box

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, antimeridian

The OSM data is in 900913. I need to get 4326, but so that the longitude's range is NOT -180..180, but rather some other, shifted range, based on a parameter. This way, if I need to draw an object near antimeridian (e.g. Alaska), I could request range of -360..0.  The leaflet will be centered at -180, and there won't be any incomplete shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The OSM data is in 900913.

Um, no, it isn't, that's just how it is displayed on the web. Almost all the OpenStreetMap APIs and planet downloads (whether `.osm.xml` or `.osm.pbf`) have coordinates in WGS84 (EPSG 4326), and so does any PostGIS column created by `osm2pgsql`. (If you obtain the OSM data in some other way that results in a different SRS in the database, you might want to elaborate on that, so that alternatives can be suggested if appropriate.)

> I need to get 4326, but so that the longitude's range is NOT -180..180, but rather some other, shifted range, based on a parameter. This way, if I need to draw an object near antimeridian (e.g. Alaska), I could request range of -360..0. The leaflet will be centered at -180, and there won't be any incomplete shapes.

In PostGIS ≥ 2.3 you can do that with [`ST_WrapX(geom, longitude_where_to_split_the_globe, -360)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_WrapX.html), e.g. to get -360..0, use `ST_WrapX(geom, 0, -360)`.

For older PostGIS versions, I don't know how to do this. (See also my own question [Is there an inverse operation to ST_Shift_Longitude in PostGIS < 2.3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/242308/51574).)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you ST_Transform(geom,4236) to transform the geometry to the required CRS.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

Then use ST_Translate(geom,x,y) to shift it to a new spot.
https://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html

Then use ST_scale(geom,xFactor,yFactor) to scale the geometry based on what you need
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Scale.html

So the total transformation SQL would end up something similar to:

```
ST_Scale(ST_Translate(ST_Transform(geom,4236),x,y),xfactor,yfactor)
```

Comment: thank you, but this does not solve the problem. I do not need new coordinates for each data point. I need to make sure that all polygon's bounding box is not -180..180, but instead some shifted value, like -360..0.  This way the islands of Alaska would not be shown both on the leftmost and rightmost sides of the screen -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Yurik/maplink#/maplink/0/1/66/4 - for this map I would specify central longitude of -110, and the bounding box would be -290..70. If a polygon goes across that boundry, I would expect postgis to cut it into two.

Comment: why can't you use @Freight_Train's solution with ST_Translate? That would shift the polygon based on any x offset that you specify. Use CASE WHEN if you only want to do this for polygons that cross 180 degrees.

Comment: Your comment suggests that you want to cut the geometries as well, into parts that are in the E and W hemispheres. If so, use ST_Split, and cut them with a line that runs from (90,180) to (-90, 180).