# Is there an inverse operation to ST_Shift_Longitude in PostGIS < 2.3?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.2, antimeridian, postgis-2.1

[`ST_Shift_Longitude(geom)`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Shift_Longitude.html) (renamed to [`ST_Shift_Longitude`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Shift_Longitude.html) in PostGIS 2.2) adds 360 to longitudes below 0, thereby (for lon-lat coordinates like WGS84) moving the part of the world "left" (west) of the 0-meridian to the "right" (east) of the "right" (eastern) antimeridian. So this turns a flat -180°…+180° map "split" around the international date line into a flat 0°…+360° map "split" at Greenwich.

**Is there any function that does the reverse** (i.e. subtracting 360 from longitudes above 180) **to get back from a flat 0°…+360° map "split" at Greenwich to a flat -180°…+180° map "split" at the antimeridian?**

In PostGIS ≥ 2.3 I could use `ST_WrapX(shifted_geom, 180, -360)`, I guess, but in PostGIS 2.1 and 2.2 `ST_WrapX` isn't available, yet.

I tried `ST_MakeValid(shifted_geom)` and `ST_Transform(shifted_geom, 4326)`, but both return the `shifted_geom` unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shifted_geom::geography` to cast the `shifted_geometry` to a geography:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    'POLYGON(
        (
            176.792 -12.2085,
            182.1313 -12.2085,
            182.1313 -20.8999,
            176.792 -20.8999,
            176.792 -12.2085
        )
    )'::geometry
);
--                                              st_astext                                             
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  POLYGON((176.792 -12.2085,182.1313 -12.2085,182.1313 -20.8999,176.792 -20.8999,176.792 -12.2085))
-- (1 row)
```

([Mike T's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192255/51574) to [Best-practices for databases and APIs with geographic data spanning the antimeridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192218/51574) made me aware that

> [c]asting a EPSG:4326 geometry to a geography type also normalizes the coordinates

which solves this nicely.)